# How do I use a for loop to print out alternating information from arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, vector

I'm really sorry for the confusing title, but I don't know how to word the question without showing you the code. So here is my problem. I am trying to print out 20 students information which is all contained in 3 different arrays (ID number, last name, and age). The arrays (and vector) are as such:

```
vector<int> studentNumber (20);
int age [20] {20, 21, 22, 42, 55, 28, 20, 20, 19,19, 22, 23, 25, 26, 24, 23, 19, 22, 21, 20};
string lastName [20] {"Simmons", "Jones", "James", "Little", "Russell", "Haynes", "Marcotte", "Kemper", "Vandergore", "Hume", "Stephens", "Jensen", "Biersack", "Sykes", "Joseph", "Dunn", "Hai", "Meteos", "Aphromoo", "Faker"};
```

I am using 3 for loops to print out all of this information and I have them all working just fine. They are as such:

```
void getAllStudentInfo() {
    for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    cout << "Student's ID number is: " << 400 + i << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << "Student's last name is: " << lastName[i] <<endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << age[i] << endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

So what they do now is print out the information as 20 ID numbers, 20 last names, and then 20 ages. What I would ideally like for them to do is print the first 3 elements from each array, and then the second three, and then the third three, and so on. So it would look like, (Id number, last name, age), repeating twenty times as opposed to (Id number x20, last name x20, age x20). How would I go about refactoring it so that it looks the way that I'd like it to?

Comment: `std::cout` the different information in the same loop.

Comment: and change the `<= 20` to `< 20`.

Comment: Do they all need to be an array to do that? That works fine when I combine the last name and age, but how do I integrate in the ID number?

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks guys.

Comment: (Small point: *"refactoring"* means changing implementation without changing behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine your for loops into one loop.
First of all your choice of data structures is unusual. Why do you mix vectors and arrays? It's probably better to use vectors for all three. Then the number of students can be determined at run-time, plus good debuggers will perform bounds checking. You should also avoid hardcoding magic numbers such as 20 in your code. It makes it harder to update your code if the number needs to change. Furthermore, I'm not sure what is the point of the `studentNumber` vector as you never store any data in it. Did you just want a counter? (Use an int)

The code to work with your data structures would be as follows:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
{
    cout << "Student's ID number is: " << 400 + i << "\n";
    cout << "Student's last name is: " << lastName[i] << "\n";
    cout << age[i] << "\n";
}
```

Depending on how you want to design your program, it may be better if you combine these three pieces of information into one object. Here is a simple way to do it:

```
struct Student
{
    Student(int id, int age, const string& name)
        : id(id), age(age), name(name)
    {}

    int id;
    int age;
    string name;
};
```

You can add niceties such as getters and setters when you learn about them later.

Now populate your data structure of students like so:

```
vector<Student> allStudents;

// optional - if you know the number of students in advance, you can give a hint to the vector to increase its performance. the number does not need to be exact and calling reserve does not increase the number of elements in the vector right away
allStudents.reserve(20);

// add student data, possibly from a file?
allStudents.push_back(Student(400, 15, "Billy"));
allStudents.push_back(Student(401, 16, "Sally"));
// alternative slightly more efficient syntax for C++11
allStudents.emplace_back(402, 15, "Jill");
```

Now there is only one data structure for you to iterate through. You can do it like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < allStudents.size(); i++)
{
    cout << "Student's ID number is: " << allStudents[i].id << "\n";
    cout << "Student's last name is: " << allStudents[i].name << "\n";
    cout << allStudents[i].age << "\n";
}
```

In C++11 you can use a more convenient syntax:

```
// remove the const keyword if you want to be able to write to student objects in the vector
for (const auto& student : allStudents)
{
    cout << "Student's ID number is: " << student.id << "\n";
    cout << "Student's last name is: " << student.name << "\n";
    cout << student.age << "\n";
}
```

Notice how your data is kept together in one logical place and you do not need to hardcode a number of students if you don't want to, and a good debugger will now perform more bounds checking.

Live example:
http://ideone.com/gsvbYa

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need or want to use direct raw arrays you can contain all of this information that is related into a class structure and you could either implement a print function on that class object or add an overloaded std::cout << stream operator function.

```
struct StudentInformation {
    unsigned m_id;
    unsigned m_age;
    std::string m_lastName;

    StudentInformation( unsigned uId, unsigned uAge, const std::string& strLastName ) :
    m_id( uId ), m_age( uAge ), m_lastName( strLastName ) {
}; 

class StudentInformationList {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const StudentInformation* const studentInformation ); 
private:
    std::vector<StudentInformation> m_vStudents;

public:
    StudentInformation();
    explicit StudentInformation( StudentInformation& studentInformation );

    void addStudentToList( const StudentInformation& studentInformation );
    std::vector<StudentInformation>& getStudentList() const;
    StudentInformation& getStudent( const unsigned id ) const;
    StudentInformation& getStudent( const std::string& strName ) const;

};
```

This would be the class declaration and from here you would have to implement the functions appropriately.

Comment: After looking at this, there is a few different ways to work with the stream operator for the std::cout object. You can either have the list use the stream operator and loop through all the objects in the list or you can add this operator to the StudentInformation structure to printData() for each instance of that object.

Answer (score 0):

- You can simply print Id ,name and age in single loop.

  ```
  void getAllStudentInfo() 
  {

    vector<int> studentNumber(20);
    int age [20] {20, 21, 22, 42, 55, 28, 20, 20, 19,19, 22, 23, 25, 26, 24, 23, 19, 22, 21, 20};
    string lastName [20] {"Simmons", "Jones", "James", "Little", "Russell", "Haynes", "Marcotte", "Kemper", "Vandergore", "Hume", "Stephens", "Jensen", "Biersack", "Sykes", "Joseph", "Dunn", "Hai", "Meteos", "Aphromoo", "Faker"};
    int i;
    for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
      cout << "Student's ID number is: " << 400 + i << endl;
      cout << "Student's last name is: " << lastName[i] <<endl;
      cout << age[i] << endl;
    }
    return;
    }
  ```